# C# reading values from datatable filled with sql select

Tags: c#

I am coding win form app, which checks on startup right of the currently logged user. I had these right saved in MS SQL server in the table. When importing data to Datatable, there is no problem. But when I want to read value, there is message "cannot find column xy".

```cs
SqlDataAdapter sdaRights = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM rights WHERE [user]='" + System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name + "'", conn);

DataTable dtRights = new DataTable(); //this is creating a virtual table  
sdaRights.Fill(dtRights);
Object cellValue = dt.Rows[0][1];
int value = Convert.ToInt32(cellValue);
MessageBox.Show(value.ToString());
```

I would like, that program would save the value from SQL to int.

Comment: I'd suggest reading up on SQL Injection ASAP.

Comment: Can we change the value of  System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name ? I know what SQL injection is but I am interested to know if we can change this value as its not a textbox or any control ?

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that you have rows being returned, would be my first guess. You should loop through your `DataTable` instead of simply trying to access element 0 in it.

```
DataTable dtRights = new DataTable();
sdaRights.Fill(dtRights);
foreach(DataRow row in dtRights.Rows) {
    Object cellValue = row[1];
    int value = Convert.ToInt32(cellValue);
    MessageBox.Show(value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: If the user column is unique (should be...) than he must return only one row.
In this case he can use SqlCommand ExecuteScalar()
It will return only the (first) selcted field from the (first) row.

Answer (score 0):

```
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("your connection string"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [column_you_want] FROM [rights] WHERE [user] = @user"))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
                con.Open();

                int right = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Instead of System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
you can use Environment.UserName